# Typescript - Date with 31st day in month gives back ISOString with 30th day

Tags: typescript, date, iso

When creating a date with

`let date = new Date(2021, 10, 31);`

the call `date.toISOString();` returns `'2021-10-30T23:00:00.000Z'`.

Is there a way to make it return the correct day in the ISOString (i.e. the 31st)?

Comment: The parameter values are evaluated against your local time zone (not UTC).

Comment: @AlekseyL. Is there a way to make them get evaluated against UTC?

Comment: You could use another constructor and provide values as string. `new Date('2021-10-31')` or better `new Date('2021-10-31T00:00:00.000Z')`. Parameters can be injected with string interpolation

Comment: The question is what you actually want to use the ISO string representation for? Because it is *correct* - it is simply in UTC but it shows the exact same point in time as if it was in the local time zone: `'2021-10-31T00:00:00.000+01:00'`

Comment: @VLAZ I am working on an application where the backend requires UTC time strings, but in the frontend local time zone should be displayed for the user